# Invoke button_Click method of MyForm.h file from .cpp file in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am using visual studio 2012. I want to invoke a button_Click event to perform "next" action in MyForm.h (coded in c#) from a switch case which is in a code.cpp file in the same project.

"code.cpp"

```
case PXCGesture::Gesture::LABEL_POSE_THUMB_UP: wprintf_s(L"[Gesture] THUMB_UP %s", data->active?L"ON":L"OFF"); 
           //BUTTON CLICK INVOCATION CODE                           
    break;
}
```

"MyForm.h"

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
 // CODE FOR THE "next" ACTION
}
```